# Nested ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a 3 level nested arrayList as follows:

```
   ArrayList<String> rowContents = new ArrayList();
   ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows;
   ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> page;
```

In the code, within different loops, the arrayLists will be populated as follows:

```
    rowContents.add("some content");
    rows.add(rowContents);
    page.add(rows);
```

Is it okay to use 3 level nested arrayLists like this? Or, is there a better approach?

Comment: "is there a better approach" For what? What is your actual problem?

Comment: When you have 3 nested `ArrayList`s, it might be a sign of a bad design.

Comment: A very bad design.. use classes instead

Comment: @LutzHorn - better approach for handling (or revising) a nested arrayList design.

Comment: Yes you can do it, but that doesn't make it a good idea. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Thanks, I too thought so. Just wanted to confirm it :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suggest to create classes for page and rows.

Internaly they can hold their children in a list:

```
public class Row {
    List<String> rowContent;
    Page parent;

    //...
}



public class Page {
    List<Row> rows;

    //...
}
```

Comment: +1 for creating classes.. Wont you think it is tree like structure.. good to craate tree object

Answer (score 1):

How about some classes for page and rows? It's easier to maintain!

```
public class Page{

private List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();

}

public class Row{

/* do some crazy stuff in it*/

}


/* all pages*/
List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<Page>();

for(Row row: pages.getRows()){
  /* do some crazy stuff with the content of the row */
}
```